# how to calculate percentage and generate below result

Tags: mysql

I have a table schema

```
CREATE TABLE `charge` (
  `charge_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `selling_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `charge_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`charge_id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `charge_type` (
  `charge_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `charge_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`charge_type_id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `charge_type_tax_list` (
  `tax_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `charge_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tax_type_id`,`charge_type_id`)
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE `tax_type` (
  `tax_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tax_type` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `percentage` decimal(5,4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0000',
  `is_deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`tax_type_id`)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO charge (
  `selling_date`,
  `amount`,
  `is_deleted`,
  `charge_type_id`
)
VALUES
("2013-12-01", 50, 0, 1), 
("2013-12-01", 20, 0, 2), 
("2013-12-02", 40, 0, 1), 
("2013-12-02", 30, 0, 3), 
("2013-12-02", 30, 1, 1), 
("2013-12-03", 10, 0, 1);
```

```
INSERT INTO charge_type (
  `charge_type_id`,
  `charge_type`,
  `is_deleted`
)
VALUES
(1, "room charge", 0), 
(2, "snack charge", 0), 
(3, "deleted charge", 1);
```

```
INSERT INTO charge_type_tax_list (
  `tax_type_id`,
  `charge_type_id`
)
VALUES
(1, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3);
```

```
INSERT INTO tax_type (
  `tax_type_id`,
  `tax_type` ,
  `percentage`,
  `is_deleted`

)
VALUES
(1, "GST", 0.05, 0),
(2, "HRT", 0.04, 0),
(3, "DELETED TAX", 0.10, 1);
```

I want you to produce a query that lists all charges and tax-calculated totals
With the given schema, your query should produce:

```
Selling Date    Charge Type Amount  Tax
2013-12-01      Room Charge  50.00  4.50
2013-12-01      Snack Charge 20.00  1.00
2013-12-02      Room Charge  40.00  3.60
2013-12-03      Room Charge  10.00  0.90
```

Do not display charges that are deleted (is_deleted is flagged)
 Do not display charges that have charge_types that are deleted (is_deleted is flagged)
 Do not consider tax_type that is deleted (is_deleted), but the containing charge_type should still be displayed)

Please help me I need it urgently.Thanks

Comment: And where is the sql query which you have tried to get the result?

Comment: I don't have knowledge about query development that's why I am asking from professionals.Please help me in this.

Comment: You can read from [www.mysqltutorial.org](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/basic-mysql-tutorial.aspx) and try to write the query. Focus on JOINS.

Comment: We really want to help, and part of the process of helping (as opposed to doing the work for you, is that you do some research on forming SQL queries on your own, and post what you have tried. That said, you have a few topics you need to work through to build up to your desired result.

Comment: @cdaiga I don't have that much time.I need it urgently so please help me on this

Comment: selling date is in the charge table

charge type is in the charge table
amount is in the charge table

the tax is not in any table, but can be calculated using data in the tables
the tax rate is in the tax_type table
the charge_type_tax_list maps between charge types and tax types
Given all that, you can join the three tables, so that the tax rates will be available.
In a query, in addition to selecting columns, you can select the result of a calculation. That looks like "SELECT AMOUNT*TAXRATE FROM T1;" if AMOUNT and TAXRATE were in table T1.

Answer (score 0):

Please read on [MySQL Join Made Easy](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/) to understand how joins are used. Here is a query that should give the result you want by joining the tables on the common attributes.

```
SELECT A.`selling_date` AS `Selling Date`, B.`charge_type` AS `Charge Type`
, A.`amount` AS `Amount`, (A.`amount` *  D.`percentage`) AS `Tax` FROM 
`charge` A LEFT JOIN  
`charge_type` B ON A.`charge_type_id`=B.`charge_type_id` INNER JOIN 
`charge_type_tax_list` C ON B.`charge_type_id`=C.`charge_type_id` 
INNER JOIN `tax_type` D ON C.`tax_type_id`=D.`tax_type_id`
WHERE 
A.`is_deleted`=0 AND B.`is_deleted`=0 AND
D.`is_deleted`=0;
```

Here is an **[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a1abf/5)**

Answer (score 0):

This query below will get the result that you want

```
select charge.selling_date as SellingDate, 
charge.amount as Amount,
charge_type.charge_type as ChargeType,
sum(charge.amount * tax_type.percentage) as Tax
From charge
inner join charge_type on charge.charge_type_id=charge_type.charge_type_id,
tax_type
where charge.is_deleted=0 and charge_type.is_deleted=0 and tax_type.is_deleted=0
group by charge.selling_date, charge.amount,charge_type.charge_type
```